# SSRS 2008: Tablix header in Subreport not repeating

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[image]I have a subreport which is usually bigger than one page. The subreport has a heading which should repeat if the subreport is more than one page.

My solution was creating a Tablix Control and put the heading in the first row. In the details row I put the subreport.

First I tried to check `Repeat header rows on each page` in the Tablix properties to achieve the repeating header, but with no success.

After some research on the internet I found an approach that was already in discussion on stackoverflow and many other sites.

It's about using the "Advanced Mode" but this approach does not work for me either

Here is the link to the second approach on stackoverflow:
[Stackoverflow Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285923/tablix-repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-not-working-report-builder-3-0)

Helps very appreciated...

Comment: Update: I didn't had the Group1 in the beginning. Had only [Static] and =[Details] I put the Group1 there afterwards because on the other explanations with screenshots, they all had a group. But unfortunately this doesn't change anything...

Comment: To make it more clear: This whole thing is a subreport, which is part of a huge report. And I want that for this subreport the blue line repeats on every site for the length of the subreport (the gray item).

Comment: I found out that even if I run only the subreport alone it doesn't show up the tablix header on the second page. It does show when I put the textbox in the page header and run only the subreport. When running the main report, which has a  page header itself, this page header is not shown at all, which is correct I guess (only one page header).

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did you get any solution for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSRS Details Group Header Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485766/ssrs-details-group-header-label)

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions that should work:

**The Simplest**

Open your subreport and move the header row into a textbox in the header of the subreport

**Slightly more Complicated**

1. Enter the Advanced Mode for the tablix containing the header row.
2. Click on the "(Static)" row that is your header row; it's probably the first/top "(Static)" row.
3. In the properties panel, you should see the row identified as "Tablix Member". If it says textbox1 or nothing at all then you need to repeat step 2.
4. Change Keep with Group property to "After".
5. Make sure Repeat on New Page to "True"

That should do it!

Comment: Thank you very much. But I'm not sure how the more complicated approach differs from my screenshot... I tried your first approach, but the result was that the page header isn't visible at all then... That's very confusing. Maybe it is because the Main report (which is not showed here has a page header itself...

Comment: I found out that the page header of a subreport is not shown if the main report has a page header.

Comment: Your keep with group needs to be "After", not "None". Your RepeatonNewPage is already set correctly in the screenshot, but make sure it is currently set to "True".

Comment: Thanks for the information on the subreport header. That will likely save me some trouble at a later date. If you have a reference for that, please share so others can investigate further.

Comment: Thank you I tried alredy all the settings of KeepWithGroup, but without success.

Comment: Here is the link to a site. There you will find the information, that subreport page headers/footers are not supported:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ba15e779-1de5-4c84-9d14-5739417c0258/subreport-headerfooter-visibility?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: I have not used subreports much, so I've upvoted your question to hopefully get someone with a little more background in here to help. Best of luck in the meantime.

Comment: Hi Christopher, your answer did the job for me. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I searched in many articles and found that the problem exists in BIDS 2008. Later Microsoft released a fix regarding this.

But, the report designed earlier won't repeat the header. It needs to be redesigned from the beginning