# SSRS Details Group Header Label

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I apologize in advance, but I am just not seeing how to do what I need in SSRS (I have plenty of dev & SQL experience but not much SSRS)

I used the Report wizard to create a very basic report to list all Active employees, their location name and their status.  Now I would like to add labels above the details but when I do those labels are repeated at each change in location and I would like them to only be at the top of the page.

Here is how the report is printing now with the detail labels at the top of each detail group:

```
Location Report 
   Office Location 1   Emp ID  Sts    Name
                       123456   A     Doe, Jane
                       987654   A     Smith, John
   Office Location 2   Emp ID  Sts    Name
                       456789   A     Martin, Joe
```

What I would like is the detail labels on the top of each page:

```
Location Report
                    Emp ID  Sts    Name 
Office Location 1
                    123456   A     Doe, Jane
                    987654   A     Smith, John
Office Location 2
                    456789   A     Martin, Joe
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me if it's just not possible?

Also, how can I get spacing after each group so it doesn't look all cramped together?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get your column headings just showing once at the top of the table, you need to insert a row outside and above the grouping:

[image]

To get a blank row after each group, you want to insert a row outside the lowest level group, but inside the main office location group:

[image]

The table should end up looking something like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**

To make the header row repeat follow these steps. Note that these settings apply to viewing the report. They do not result in any changes when exporting to Excel.

1. In the Grouping view click the black arrow on the right and select “Advanced Mode”

[image]

2. Select the “Static” group member

[image]

3. (Optional) Set “FixedData” to True to get the header to scroll.
   •   Set a background color for the header (even if it’s white) so that it doesn’t overlap other elements as it scrolls. The default is “No Color” which is transparent.
4. Set “KeepWithGroup” to “After” and “RepeatOnNewPage” to True to get the header to repeat on each page.

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly!  However, now I see that the titles are only on the first page - is there a way to get the titles on the top of each page?  and maybe repeat the location information as well in order to see that information after a page break?

Comment: @Leslie I added instructions to make the row headers repeat on each page.