# Repeating column headers for SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Thank you in advance for your help. My issue is that I have created a stepped report that looks like the below in the designer:

[image]

And produces results such as (fake data):

[image]

The issue I am having is that for people with lots of job changes, sometimes that runs on to a new page when exporting to PDF and I cannot find a way to get the column headers to repeat (Item, Change Date, Before, After etc...) such as:

[image]

I have followed all of the steps in [This MSDN article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627566%28v=sql.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [This MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/display-headers-and-footers-with-a-group-report-builder-and-ssrs) to no avail. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: click tablix and properties.. should have a option to repeat row header to every page.

Comment: click on the Static under EMP (ROW Group) and then properties window on the right hand side.. Select.. KeepWithGroup -> AFTER and RepeatonNewPage -> TRUE. Do this for both the Static elements under the row group.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you for that! I was getting confused on row groups vs column groups and such and didn't implement the above correctly the first time.

Comment: sweet.. I'll put that down as an answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSRS Details Group Header Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485766/ssrs-details-group-header-label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Static under EMP (ROW Group) and then properties window on the right hand side.. Select.. KeepWithGroup -> AFTER and RepeatonNewPage -> TRUE. Do this for both the Static elements under the row group.