# Tablix Headers repeating on PDF exports, but not Word

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I had a problem with SSRS 2008 R2 reports where tablix headers were not repeating on PDF and Word exports...they would only show on the first page.

So I followed the nice directions on this post:

[stackoverflow solution to tablix header not repeating on all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285923/tablix-repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-not-working-report-builder-3-0)

So now it works, but only on PDF reports. My tablix header rows only repeat for PDF, and not for WORD export. I followed directions to the letter. Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: The directions I followed at the link I provided were the ones that were marked as the Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation in Word and pagination will not work. Here is a link that details this limitation -
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283105(v=sql.105).aspx#WordLimitations

> Word does not repeat header rows on page two and greater, although you
>   set the RepeatOnNewPage property of the static header row in a tablix
>   (table, matrix, or list) to True. You can define explicit page breaks
>   in your report to force header rows to appear on new pages. However,
>   because Word applies its own pagination to the rendered report
>   exported to Word, results might vary and the header row might not
>   repeat predictably. The static header row is the row that contains the
>   column headings.