# SSRS: Row not repeating on every page

Tags: reporting-services

I have set up a simple tablix with two rows.  The upper row has a value that I want repeated on every page, and the lower row contains a subreport.

I have tried setting the static row group RepeatOnNewPage to true and I have tried creating a table, putting the upper value in the header and setting headers to repeat on every page.  Neither of these have worked; the upper row value will only show on the first page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tablix: Repeat header rows on each page not working - Report Builder 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285923/tablix-repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-not-working-report-builder-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to pass the value in the upper row down as a parameter into the subreport.  It now shows up on every page.