# SSRS group by multiple fields and groupings

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I have a query that returns the following fields:

GrantCode

EmplID

EmployeeFullName

AssignedUnit

DaysOff

HourlyRate

CalendarEventStart

CalendarEventEnd

NumberOfHours

StatuteNumber

ViolationDescription

I want to have a stepped SSRS report that shows:
[image]
the calendar start time, end time and number of hours under the employee name info and then another grouping that shows the citations that were issued during the time period.  I can't quite figure out how to get the SSRS groups set up to display in this manner.

I currently have all the data in a single query/data set but can separate it if that will make the reporting easier.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!
Leslie

Comment: you could build a sub report and use the EmpID as the toggle and the argument to the sub report that breaks out the detail.

Answer (score 4):

Add a tablix to your report. Put in the tablix the fields `Citation Number, Statue Number, Violation Description, Number of Citations`. Then go to **Row Groups > Add Group > Parent Group** chose for group by the `EmplID` and check the **Add group header**, then hit OK.

Afterwards click on the most left column in your tablix and chose **Insert Column > Inside Group - Right**. Do this a few times and put in these colums the fields `EmployeeFullName, Assigned Unit, HourlyRate, DaysOff, StartTime, EndTime`.

Then go to your **Row Groups** and click on the drop down by `(Details)` and chose **Group Properties > Visibilty** and check **Display can be toggled by this report item:**. Here you have to chose the name of the textbox where the `EmplID` field is. Now the detail data get toggled by the `EmplID`.

If you want other data to display just add another column and put your fields or expressions in this column. A new column before the two dotted lines is on the group level and column after the two dotted lines are for the detail section.

Comment: Thanks so much!!  I will go try this right now :)  ps I love your username!

Comment: Thanks. Did the job for me.  The only thing I will add is that I am new to Report Server and so I did not know how to add a tablix.  Tablix is a table, which is available in the toolbox.  If you were new to this like I was then you will also need to add the necessary components to Visual Studio - see the Microsoft [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15) -  get the data tools update under Tools, Extensions and Updates, for Community 2019.

Comment: The other missing element - repeating the header on every page when using groups - see this SA [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285923/tablix-repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-not-working-report-builder-3-0).